# Create shareable link after AJAX load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On my page, a content container holds different information depending which list item was clicked (news, video, blog, etc.) 
This is achieved by loading in html snippets with jQuery's load method like this:

```
$('#container').load('blog.html'); // file from my domain
```

After the load, I can update the URL using this:

```
window.history.pushState("www.mysite.com", "mysite", "/blog");
```

Or change hash:

```
window.location.hash = "blog";
```

When the link is visited directly, this causes an error because there is no knowledge of such a page on my host.  After the AJAX load, I'm wondering what the best way would be to make the current state of the page shareable ( I send the link to someone, and when they visit it, they see the state of the page as it was when I shared the link)? The link would be something like: `www.mysite.com/blog`.

The `AJAX` load:

```
$('li a').on('click', function(){

    var file = this.id;
    $('#container').load(file +'.html');

    // window.history.pushState("www.mysite.com", "mysite", "/" + file); or..
    // window.location.hash = file;
    return false;
});
```

**P.S.** I would like to avoid using `php` for the sake of simplicity, but am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you use the hash, as you already state in OP, you should have no errors when you visit it directly. ( example: `www.mysite.com/#blog` )

On load javascript can check if a hash is set, and do the necessary ajax calls again to serve the page from a direct link. (PHP cannot see the hash by the way, so using only the hash, will not be controllable from PHP server side.)

```
$.ready( function() {
  if (window.location.hash == "blog") $(#container).load("blog.html");
});
```

Using pushState (example:  `www.mysite.com/blog` ) is a different story... That one would need you to create a .htaccess that will rewrite to (for example) the index.php. Index.php could then have javascript-logic that looks at the requested url, to load the desired content again with Ajax. (Or even without ajax, if you do it in PHP)

javascript (after configuring .htaccess to rewrite to the file holding this javascript):

```
$.ready( function() {
  if (window.location.pathname == "/blog") $(#container).load("blog.html");
});
```

or in php (after configuring .htaccess to rewrite to the file holding this php):

```
<div id="container">
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/blog") {
        include("blog.html");
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On page load, check for window.hash. If it is not empty, then do the same thing that you do when an `<a>` is clicked in your `<ul>`. But to not to reinvent the wheel, have a look at javascript routers, for example [crossroads.js](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/).

Comment: What about when window.history.pushState is used?